# How to stop text going under or over picture

Tags: html, css

Text goes over the picture but i need a new line every time it hits that picture. HTML and CSS are bellow. Can I do it with just float right with picture or I need something other. Also text cannot go under border of his paragraph while resized.

```
 img{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        align:right;

        margin-left: 125px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-left: 120px;


    }

    .participation{


        position: relative;
        height: 250px;
        width: 50%;
    }

    p{
        position: absolute;
    }
```

HTML

```
<body id="css-zen-garden">
<div class="page-wrapper">



    <div class="main supporting" id="zen-supporting" role="main">


        <div class="participation" id="zen-participation" role="article">
            <h3>Participation</h3>
            <p>Strong visual design has always been our focus. You are modifying this page, so strong <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> skills are necessary too, but the example files are commented well enough that even <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> novices can use them as starting points. Please see the <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/resources/" title="A listing of CSS-related resources"><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Resource Guide</a> for advanced tutorials and tips on working with <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>.</p>
            <img src="zebra_shark1.jpg">
```

[What paragraph should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikq3b.png)

[Whole task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPfjt.png)

Comment: Show your HTML as well.

Comment: Don't position it `absolutely` -- by doing so you are removing it from the flow of the page hence it isn't acknowledged by other elements, I.E. your text. Sidenote: `align` is not a valid CSS property.

Answer (score 3):

For this you need to stop using `position: absolute`. You can achieve your desired behaviour with floats:

```css
p {
   max-width: 500px; /*set width for demo purposes, so that you see the text wrapping*/
}
   
img {
 float: right
}
```

```html
<p>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what `position: absolute` is supposed to do. When you use `position: absolute` is like you are telling the browser: "ignore the other elements, the final positions will be given by these coordinates (through the `left` and `top` properties)".

If this is not what you want - and probably it is not - just don't use `position: absolute`, but try `position: relative` or `float: left`.

There is not an easy answer for your question, since thinking of to structure the code ups to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not position your image absolute, because the element gets taken from its context. That's why your text overlaps the image, because it doesn't know the image is there.

You could try to use `float:right` on your image.

Comment: I need to position that img on top right corner, I can do it but if I resize the screen it moves a lot. Also I need do that with text which goes outside the box if I resize it.

Comment: What do you mean with 'It moves a lot'? I don't completely understand what you need exactly.